# Swift: UILabel has weird outlines?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

Ok, I have never experienced this but don't know how to make it go away: I have programmatically created several UILabels that have a certain background color. On some, however, on the upper and right borders this a weird darker line visible (see 2nd row of labels):

I don't know what is causing this. 
Here is how I made them:

```
 for i in 0...featureLabels.count-1
            {
                featureLabels[i] = RSSLinkLabel()
                featureLabels[i]?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (overallWidth-(imgSpace))/3, height: ((overallWidth-(imgSpace))/3)/contentRatios[2])
                featureLabels[i]?.text = "Hello label \(i)"
                featureLabels[i]?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: secondColorStr)
                featureLabels[i]?.textAlignment = .left
                featureLabels[i]?.font = iphoneFont

                var pt = CGPoint()
                switch i {
                case 0:
                    pt = CGPoint(x: sideDiff + ((featureLabels[i]?.bounds.width)!/2), y: subContView2.bounds.height - ((featureLabels[i]?.bounds.height)!/2))
                case 1:
                    pt = CGPoint(x: subContView2.bounds.width/2, y: subContView2.bounds.height - ((featureLabels[i]?.bounds.height)!/2))
                case 2:
                    pt = CGPoint(x: sideDiff + (overallWidth - ((featureLabels[i]?.bounds.width)!/2)), y: subContView2.bounds.height - ((featureLabels[i]?.bounds.height)!/2))
                default:
                    break
                }
                featureLabels[i]?.center = pt

                subContView2.addSubview(featureLabels[i]!)
            }
```

They are custom labels that I have subclassed here:

```
import UIKit

class RSSLinkLabel: UILabel {

    var id = String()

    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)

    }
    func customInit()
    {
        self.text = txtSources[id]
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }
    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        customInit()
    }

}
```

I have tried doing `featureLabels[i]?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor` but nothing happens.

How can I make that outline go away?

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Use debug view hierarchy and post a image to see if there is something

Comment: Is this on a real device or simulator?

Comment: @AliBeadle both

Comment: @ReinierMelian how do I do that? I don't know how to get debut view

Comment: Does any of your math ever work out to fractions as far as your frames go?

Comment: Ah.. yeah @solenoid why would that cause the outline?

Comment: Sub-pixel approximation if it turns out to be the issue I think. Were you able to round off the dimensions and see if it still happened?

Comment: That was it. thank you!